# Styles for IE if lt [IE 12]

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-9

Look this site please: http://test.k-38.ru — try to open it in it, opera, chrome or ie 9+. All is good.

But try in IE <= 8. Look this image: [image: site]

This is how site is shown for users which use IE <= 8.

I know that some IE don't support modern tags, but I thought it will cause some... hmm... colors problem (btw look it in IE 5.5, 6 :DD welcome problems with colors).

How I can find parts in my html and css which are shown bad in IE, so I can find ways to re-structure html or add some rows to css to remove this bug.

I know about `if` statements in html, which will help me to include css files only for exactl browser. The question is not how to do this, the question is how to find parts of code, which are shown bad in old IE versions.

Also, I want to ask about it more experienced users :) You, so member :)

Is there any tool to watch css code in IE6-9 like firebug? Or only HTML source?

Answer (score 1):

You can use IE css selector hacks

[For more information](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/browser-specific-hacks/)

Comment: I know all of this constructions. The problem is how to detect parts in code, which are shown bad, not how to add css file only for exact IE version.

Comment: Sorry I changed my answer, this what I supposed to answer. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Now there are tonns of code without any comments:D nice! great part on german (?) :D ok I will try something. thank you. I will tell you about result.

Comment: Wait. All this css hacks have to be situated in their own css? And that css files have to be included in if statement?

Comment: In their own css and yes included in if statement.

Comment: Well. Nice. Or not. It is really copy past of code on source page Oo!!! Seems to me you want +, not to help. It is just list of css hacks, which will help me to set color somewhere. I have problems with heights, for example, not with colors.

Comment: ha ha.. you got things wrong. color is just the example, you can have your property in place of color. In your case include height.
Well I am I supposed to type whole lot of code here or be smart copy and paste it?

Comment: Here by this post I meant to show the css selector which differ in IE from others.

Comment: Better way was to just give a link to source page and explain code, I think. Thanks for your help. Is there any tool to watch css code in IE6-9 like firebug? Or only HTML source?